# Should I color the edited sentences in a minor revision?

Tags: peer-review, journals, conference

My paper has been accepted with minor revision.
When I revise the paper, should I mark the edited sentences by using a different color like for a major revision?

Comment: Please run your edits through a color blindness simulator to make sure that it's not something that is invisible to color blind individuals.

Comment: @user while this is essential for the published version, it’s unlikely to be an issue for the final revisions unless the entire editing team is colour-blind.  Indeed the American Physical Society produces “red-line” galleys with colors for easy reference by the authors.

Comment: @user - Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't colour blindness normally prevent you from distinguishing between a pair of colours, rather than black and a colour? I'd assume you're only going to be submitting to a journal in black text... Then again, as I'm writing this, I suppose figures can be coloured in some journals

Comment: @ScottishTapWater There are various types of color blindness. In the case of total color blindness, you'd be expecting someone to pick out revisions that are slightly different shades of black from the regular black text.

Comment: @user - To be honest, I didn't even realise total colour-blindness was a thing... Every day's a school day. I suppose in that case, the better option would be to weight the text differently?

I don't actually know the rules of what journal they're submitting to, but if it's minor changes in latex, and they're allowed, I'd submit a patch file along with my submission. Can't be clearer than that.

Comment: You should follow whatever instructions you were given to the letter.  Anything else can just interrupt the workflow involved in getting the paper into press.  If not instructed to highlight changes, you should not highlight changes.

Answer (score 10):

You should:

1. make a list of detailed corrections, indicating the lines and the changes in text, and referencing the referee report or comments of the editor,
2. and/or change font color.

This last is especially good so the referee or editor can easily check that suitable changes have been made.  I usually do both, irrespective of the “level” of revision required.

Comment: Check the journal guidelines. Frequently, the second option is not allowed or not possible with the journal's submission system. (Although, in OP's case ot appears to be possible.)

Comment: I’d add that if you’re using LaTeX, there are ways colouring text that can be easily undone by editing a few, localised lines in the tex files. I suspect if you’re using "styles" in Word, it also might be possible to define (and redefine) a style to be coloured (or, later, uncoloured), or you could use the "review" tool which can be easily turned off. Make sure you save your future self (and/or the journal typesetters) some effort if you’re adding colour.

Comment: For latex, latexdiff has turned out to be a really useful tool.

Comment: @Pam Don't do that!  Latexdiff.

Comment: Thanks @AnonymousPhysicist and@WolfgangBangerth, I hadn’t heard of it. It looks effort saving!

Answer (score 1):

> should I mark the edited sentences by using a different color

You should use a tool that automatically marks the changes, like Latexdiff or track changes.

Comment: “Track changes” gives me nightmares…. 

Comment: And if you use an alternative it should be readily "turn off-able". (Wish I’d thought to put this as an actual answer! +1)